Play Console Warning: Update your Play Core Maven dependency to an Android 14 compatible version
Received a warning in the Play Console saying the following

Update your Play Core Maven dependency to an Android 14 compatible version! Your current Play Core library is incompatible with targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which introduces a backwards-incompatible change to broadcast receivers to improve user security. As a reminder, from August 31, Google Play requires all new app releases to target Android 14. Update to the latest Play Core library version dependency to avoid app crashes

I would like to know, what can I possibly do to solve this problem?
My app is a complete native app, using Java/Kotlin and XML/Jetpack Compose

Check this link https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#playcore-migration

First and foremost, it's important to see that they've included a Migration link in the warning. So we need to migrate the Tasks class as per that
Later, we can split the monolithic play-core SDK into the required dependencies, as per the app requirement. The alternative SDKs can be found here
In my case, had to get the In-App Review and In-App updates SDK, seperately
EDIT:
For hybrid apps, we can go the android folder
cd android

And run the following command to check all the dependencies listed in the app, and check which one has the com.google.android.play:core dependency, by exporting all the dependencies to a text file dependencies.txt
./gradlew app:dependencies > dependencies.txt

Once you figure out, which of your dependencies uses the play core library, you can actually update it

There's nothing to replace MissingSplitsManagerFactory which is part of the Play Core library.
It's been deprecated for a long time but there has been no replacement for it other than a that Play Protect will take care of it.
But I'm still able to side load a base.apk with Play Protect enabled on a device and it crashes.

Link says that it's blocked Android 10+. What's your use case?

I'm able to build an aab bundle, unzip it and install the .../splits/base-master.apk onto a device using adb. Nothing prevents me from doing that. When I open the app it crashes with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libsqlite3x.so" not found. But that's probably not the only error case. A workaround in the past would be to check for a missing resource. But MissingSplitsManager saved having to do that.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aefyr.sai

In my case, i saw react-native-store-review package using core:1.10.3, when i update that package, everything have fixed

Step 1 (Updating dependencies)
Open the build.gradle (Module: app) file, find the library implementation below and remove it.
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'

Add or change it with the 2 new libraries implementation below and Sync now.
implementation 'com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0'

enter image description here
Step 2 (Updating MainActivity.java)
Open the MainActivity.java file, find the following code below, for quick search, use Ctrl + F.
import com.google.android.play.core.tasks.Task;

Replace it with the code below, to make it faster, you can use Ctrl + R to replace the code with a new one:
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

enter image description here

com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1 has the same issue and there is no new version

Problem Statement:
The Play Core Java and Kotlin Library has been partitioned into multiple per-feature Android libraries. That's why google shows warning or sdk issue messages into console account or throws error into terminal.
Solution:
Remove any imports of the old Play Core libraries in your build.gradle file.
Scenario:
In my case i was using this "In-App-Update" (https://github.com/prongbang/inapp-update) old library which includes
dependencies {
    api 'com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1'
}

Later i'd to remove that library and added these libraries, here's the final look of my apps build.gradle.kts file.
    dependencies {
        //implementation("com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3")
        //implementation("com.github.prongbang:inapp-update:1.0.1")

        // This dependency is downloaded from the Google’s Maven repository.
        // Make sure you also include that repository in your project's build.gradle file.
        implementation("com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0")
    
        // For Kotlin users, also import the Kotlin extensions library for Play In-App Update:
        implementation("com.google.android.play:app-update-ktx:2.1.0")
    }

And my settings.gradle.kts file look like this:
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

Happy conding :)

If you use navigation libraries:
Go to gradle - change your nav library version from 2.7.7 to 2.8.0-beta06. Go to the file -> project structure -> suggestions - warning magically gone.
Dependencies list:

So this warning is completely up to Google – or have this warning or use the beta version of the library.

This one is the solution that just had. Funny how we have to upgrade to beta Google software in order to update Google Android app.

Go to File -> Project Structure -> Click on Suggestions

This error message will shown , click on View Usage
Here will show all the dependencies that are dependent on the com.google.android.play:feature-delivery. Simply update all the dependencies.


This is not related

@gtxtreme
Can you please let me know.
Why this is not related.
I was not able to get the dependency graph for my app.
Checking on suggestion is same as seeing on dependency graph

i also got this problem:-
Update your Play Core Maven dependency to an Android 14 compatible version! Your current Play Core library is incompatible with targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which introduces a backwards-incompatible change to broadcast receivers to improve user security. As a reminder, from August 31, Google Play requires all new app releases to target Android 14. Update to the latest Play Core library version dependency to avoid app crashes: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#playcore-migration
Solution:-
Go To Android Studio.
File->ProjectStructure.
Click Suggestions.
There are two options on right side: All Modules AND Apps.
Select Apps.
Top Of the Window Shows Google play core 1.10.3 Click This .
List of dependencies Showned.
Check 1.10.3  version dependency and if its here Click the dependency  and then  click Minus(-) Option and then build your project your problem is solved. Hope It Helps
