There are new SDK issues com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1
I get the following message after submitting my app to the play store:

com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1 Google Play Core
(com.google.android.play:core) has added this note for SDK version
1.9.1:
Update your Play Core Maven dependency to an Android 14 compatible
version! Your current Play Core library is incompatible with
targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which introduces a
backwards-incompatible change to broadcast receivers to improve user
security. As a reminder, from August 31, Google Play requires all new
app releases to target Android 14. Update to the latest Play Core
library version dependency to avoid app crashes:
Its a native app using java and xml layouts and I've looked and cant
find any reference to com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1 anywhere in
the app.

I've no idea how to update the reference to get rid of the warning and still have everything working.
Any ideas?
These are the dependencies in my build file.
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation "androidx.core:core:1.7.0-alpha01"
implementation 'com.github.takusemba:spotlight:2.0.5'
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.3.5"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:2.3.5"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha04"


Update to the latest version, which right now is 1.10.3. You will find references to libraries like this in your Gradle build files.

I cant see any reference to the version mentioned in the warning.....
These are the dependencies in my project
I've added the dependencies in the project to the original question.
really not sure where to look...

Make sure that you are on the latest versions of all of those, and try to get rid of androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0. One of those libraries itself depends on com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1. My guess is that it is com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps, and for that you could upgrade to either 18.2.0 or 19.0.0.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78646430/play-console-warning-update-your-play-core-maven-dependency-to-an-android-14-co

I've updated all of the versions and removed the legacy-support one.
All still seems to work ok but now its saying that there is another issue.
com.google.android.play:feature-delivery:2.0.1
Guessing that will be a similar issue. Will have to go through them one by one to see where that is coming from.
appreciate the help.

Check your project dependencies using the Gradle command ./gradlew app:dependencies. You should see the artifact com.google.android.play:feature-delivery:2.0.1 listed under at least one of your dependencies. If it’s present, update this dependency to ensure it uses a more recent version of the com.google.android.play:feature-delivery artifact.
